# C program 2d array problems adding values

Tags: multidimensional-array, 2d

I am new to C programming and can't seem to get my 2d array to function correctly.  I know i don't have much data to input, but all the remaining array allocations should be zero.  When i compile and run it.  I get some huge numbers and I can't understand what's wrong.

```
/***************  PREPROCESSOR DIRECTIVES  *****************/

#include<stdio.h>
void printArr( double a[5][4] );


/*****************  MAIN FUNCTION  *********************/

int main(void)
{


/************  DECLARATION OF VARIABLES *****************/

int PRODUCT = 5;
int SALESPERSON = 4;
int DAY = 10;
int x, y , z;

/********** THE EXECUTABLE PART OF THE PROGRAM  ***********/

    //initialize array for product, salesperson, and day
    double arr[5][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5};

    printArr(arr);
}// closes main method

void printArr( double arr[5][4] ){

 /********** Declaration of Variables **************/
    double value;
    int PRODUCT = 5;
    int SALESPERSON = 4;
    int x,y,z,i,j;
    int eleven = 11;
    double productone, producttwo,productthree,productfour,productfive = 0;
    double salesone, salestwo, salesthree, salesfour = 0;
    double totalproduct, totalperson, totalsales = 0;
    double totproducttenone, totproducttentwo, totproducttenthree = 0;
    double totproducttenfour, totproducttenfive = 0;
    double totsalestenone, totsalestentwo, totsalestenthree = 0;
    double totsalestenfour= 0;

    //for loop for the days
    for(x = 1; x < eleven; x++){  

            productone = 0;
            producttwo = 0;
            productthree = 0;
            productfour = 0;
            productfive = 0;
            salesone =  0;
            salestwo = 0;
            salesthree = 0;

            //prints the day
            printf("\n Day %i\n", x);

            //for loop for the rows
            for(y = 0; y < PRODUCT; y++){

                    //for loop for the columns
                    for(z = 0; z < SALESPERSON; z++){ 

                            i = 0;
                            i = y + 1; 
                            j = 0;
                            j = z + 1;
                            printf("\n---------------------------------");
                            printf("\n|Product: %i  |  Salesperson: %i  |\n", i, j);
                            printf("      sales total  = %d", arr[y][z]);

                            //adds up product 1
                            if(y == 0){

                                    productone = productone + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for product 1

                            //adds up product 2
                            if(y == 1){

                                    producttwo = producttwo + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for product 2

                            //adds up product 3
                            if(y == 2){

                                    productthree = productthree + arr[y][z];

                            }// closes if for product 3

                            //adds up product 4
                            if(y ==3){

                                    productfour = productfour + arr[y][z];

                           }//closes if for product 4

                            //adds up product 5
                            if(y == 4){

                                    productfive = productfive + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for product 5

                            //adds up salesperson 1
                            if(z == 0){

                                    salesone = salesone + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for salesperson one

                            //adds up salesperson 2
                            if(z == 1){

                                    salestwo = salestwo + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for salesperson 2


                            //adds up salesperson 3
                            if(z == 2){

                                    salesthree = salesthree + arr[y][z];

                            }//closes if for sales person 3

                            //adds up salesperson 4
                            if(z == 3){

                                    salesfour = salesfour + arr[y][z];

                            }// closes if for salesperson 4


                            //if for totalsales
                            if(arr[y][z] != 0){

                            totalsales = totalsales + arr[y][z];

                            }// closes if for totalsales  

                            //adds up the total amount sold for products
                            totalproduct = productone + producttwo + productthree + productfour + productfive;

                            //adds up the totale amoun sold for salesperson
                            totalperson = salesone + salestwo + salesthree + salesfour;


                    }//closes loop for columns
            }//closes loop for rows

            //prints the sales figures for the day
            printf("\nHere are the sales figures for each product,");
            printf("\nsales person, total amount sold for today:\n");
            printf("\nTotal sales for product 1 is: %d", productone);
            printf("\nTotal sales for product 2 is: %d", producttwo);
            printf("\nTotal sales for product 3 is: %d", productthree);
            printf("\nTotal sales for product 4 is: %d", productfour);
            printf("\nTotal sales for product 5 is: %d", productfive);
            printf("\nTotal sales for salesperson 1 is: %d", salesone);
            printf("\nTotal sales for salesperson 2 is: %d", salestwo);
            printf("\nTotal sales for salesperson 3 is: %d", salesthree);
            printf("\nTotal sales for salesperson 4 is: %d", salesfour);
            printf("\nThe totalsales of products sold today is: %d\n", totalproduct);

            totproducttenone = totproducttenone + productone;
            totproducttentwo = totproducttentwo + producttwo;
            totproducttenthree = totproducttenthree + productthree;
            totproducttenfour = totproducttenfour + productfour;
            totproducttenfive = totproducttenfive + productfive;
            totsalestenone = totsalestenone + salesone;
            totsalestentwo = totsalestentwo + salestwo;
            totsalestenthree = totsalestenthree + salesthree;
            totsalestenfour = totsalestenfour + salesfour;


    }//closes loop for days

    //prints the sales for the past ten days
    printf("\nThe total of sales over the past ten days is: %d\n\n", totalsales);
    printf("\nThe total sales for product 1 for the past ten days is: %d", totproducttenone);


}//closes printarr function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue's

1)  You've declared all the variables as double and using '%d' which is the format specifier of int data type to print the values, So **change all the %d into %f** (careful; only for the elements which are declared as double )in the printf statements

2)  I don't know whether this is a feature or a you intended the program to be in this manner.

The array

```
double arr[5][4] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5};
```

have to contain 20 elements , but there is only 14 elements,so value of remaining 6 elemnts is taken as 0. This results in error ,

printing

```
---------------------------------
|Product: 4  |  Salesperson: 4  |
      sales total  = 0.000000
---------------------------------
|Product: 5  |  Salesperson: 1  |
      sales total  = 0.000000
---------------------------------
|Product: 5  |  Salesperson: 2  |
      sales total  = 0.000000
---------------------------------
|Product: 5  |  Salesperson: 3  |
      sales total  = 0.000000
---------------------------------
|Product: 5  |  Salesperson: 4  |
      sales total  = 0.000000
```

Because the array doesn't have any value for that position, so might wanna change that.